# How can i automatically insert the current user_id after submitting a form in Filament v3.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I'm currently working on a project in FilamnentPHP v3 and I am trying to figure out how to automatically pass the current user_id to my database-entity.

I thought of creating a hidden input-field and setting the default value of the field to the current user_id. But it seems like Filament ignores the hidden() TextInput and inserts null or does simply nothing.

**My wrong solution**

```
TextInput::make('user_id')
        ->label(__('messages.created_by'))
        ->required()
        ->default(
              Filament::auth()->id()
        )->readOnly()
            ->hidden()
```

So is there any way to pass values automatically to the database after the form-submit in Filament v3.

I also tried to look through the Filament-docs but I had, no real luck finding something that helps me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found out that it is possible to edit the create Page of the specific resource and add:

PATH: `./app/Filament/Resources/MyResource/Pages/CreateMyResource.php`

```
    protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
    {
        $data['user_id'] = auth()->id();

        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating an observer for the model.

```php
class PostObserver
{
  public function creating(Post $post)
  {
    if (!isset($post->user_id) && auth()->check()) {
      $post->user_id = auth()->id();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this way.
for example,if you want to insert the auth user id to blog table (created_by) so you can track who created this blog.
you can use model event in event service provider:
like this. and it will work.

```
   /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
        Blog::creating(function($blog){
            $blog->created_by = auth()->id();
            });

            Blog::updating(function($blog){
                $blog->updated_by = auth()->id();
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TextInput, the user can use the Hidden class.

The hidden component allows you to create hidden fields in your form that hold value:

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\Hidden;
 
Hidden::make('token')

[Hidden form - builder][1]
```

Comment: hahah. i have also tried hidden. with hidden the id gets ignored completly.

Answer (score 0):

If the `used_id` is used to ensure user ownership of a record, the recommended way is done via an `observer` as described in [Laravel 10 documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#observers):

```
class PostObserver
{
    public function creating(Post $post): void
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $post->user_id = auth()->id();
        }
    }
}
```

and register the `PostObserver` in `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`:

```
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Observers\PostObserver;

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Post::observe(PostObserver::class);
    }
```